# Querying by meta keys in wordpress URL string

Tags: php, wordpress

I feel like I've been all around the web and back again looking for an answer to this and it's really starting to grind my gears.

Not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but I want to add a query_posts array to a URL in the form of a query_arg. This is our query:

```
query_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'rank', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'paged' => $paged,
```

How do I use add_query_arg to pass that to the URL so as to re-order the posts with that meta_key/query_posts array?
I tried this, it doesn't seem to change the order of the posts, there's something I'm missing here.

```
<a href="<?php echo $by_rank;?>">  Rank </a>
     <?php $by_rank= esc_url(add_query_arg(array('meta_key' => 'rank',  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'))); ?>
```

The reason I want to add the query vars to the URL string is so users can sort posts on category pages based on the meta_key/meta_value. Sort of in a similar way to doing ?orderby=date, except with a meta_key.

This can be done, right? Because I'm seriously starting to think it's not possible.

From Rahil's answer

```
<?php
$meta_key = (isset($_GET['meta_key'])) ?
            sanitize_text_field($_GET['meta_key']) : 'rank'; // use default value here ''

$orderby = (isset($_GET['orderby'])) ?
           sanitize_text_field($_GET['orderby']) : 'meta_value_num'; // use default value here ''

$order = (isset($_GET['order'])) ?
         sanitize_text_field($_GET['order']) : 'DESC'; // use default value here ''

$by_rank = esc_url(add_query_arg(array(
    'meta_key' => $meta_key,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order
)));
?>
<a href="<?php echo $by_rank;?>">  Rank </a>
```

Put in the values, the same values that work fine with a query_posts array on other pages, posts don't re-order.

Answer (score 1):

The answer:-

```
function wpse139657_orderby(){
    if( isset($_GET['orderby']) ){
        $order = $_GET['order'] or 'DESC';
        set_query_var('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        set_query_var('meta_key', $_GET['orderby']);
        set_query_var('order', $order);
    }
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpse139657_orderby');
```

Create a pre_get_posts filter and just pass the meta_key name to the URL like so ?orderby=rank

Answer (score 0):

You are actually doing `add_query_arg` fine but echoing the variable before assigning it some value is your problem.

```
<a href="<?php echo $by_rank;?>">  Rank </a>
--------------------^^^^^^^^ ----->> undefined variable

 <?php $by_rank= esc_url(add_query_arg(array('meta_key' => 'rank',  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'))); ?>
 ------^^^^^^^^ ----> Now its defined.
```

Change to this: (Remember Code runs from top to bottom)

```
<?php
$meta_key = (isset($_GET['meta_key'])) ?
            sanitize_text_field($_GET['meta_key']) : ''; // use default value here ''

$orderby = (isset($_GET['orderby'])) ?
           sanitize_text_field($_GET['orderby']) : ''; // use default value here ''

$order = (isset($_GET['order'])) ?
         sanitize_text_field($_GET['order']) : ''; // use default value here ''

$by_rank = esc_url(add_query_arg(array(
    'meta_key' => $meta_key,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order
)));
?>
<a href="<?php echo $by_rank;?>">  Rank </a>
```

Now `$by_rank` has been assigned a value and you can echo it. It will output

```
/?meta_key=rank&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC
```

**Edit:**

Now you have to put above variables `$meta_key`, `$orderby` and `$order` to your `query_posts()` function:

Like this:

```
query_posts(array(
    'meta_key' => $meta_key,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order,
    'paged' => $paged
));
```

Now changing query strings from url will affect the `query_posts()`

Comment: Tried that, for some reason it STILL doesn't re-order the posts. I have a page template with that query on it and that works just fine re-ordering the posts, but for some reason a URL string won't do anything. This one is really starting to get to me.

Comment: What it does, is just adds the string to the URL but the posts are in the same order. Weird.

Comment: Did you try input values on your query_posts from url with `$_GET`

Comment: I did not, how do I do that?

Comment: So actually you need to query those fields which are appended to url right?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I need to do!

Comment: @andy What do you mean by reorder? Try changing `DESC` to `ASC`?

Comment: Re-order as in order by the meta_key. If I change to ASC it does indeed re-order the posts from oldest - newest. It's still ignoring the meta_key though, which is the thing I want it to order by. Am I being stupid about this? On the page that I have my query_posts array it orders by 'rank' in descending order (rank being posts most voted on), when I pass the string to the URL it merely orders by date, DESC or ASC.

Comment: Yeah, hence meta_value_num instead of meta_value (I think).

Comment: The query array I use on pages `query_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'rank', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ,  'paged' => $paged, ) );`

Comment: The query by default works fine but not work with query strings from url?

Comment: Yup, exactly. URL becomes `http://localhost:8888/?meta_key=rank&orderby=meta_value_num&order=ASC` and sorts posts in ascending order, but ignores the meta key. Running the query_posts on the page however, works just fine.

Comment: Any idea why that'd be?

Comment: @andy See my edit. I was missing a part :). And remember your `query_posts()` comes after the variables declaration.